# TouchBar appears on the screen when clicked

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

When I try to adjust the volume, the TouchBar appears on my screen. I tried to refresh the TouchBar agent by killing it, it doesn't work. And another problem about this issue is I cannot smoothly adjust the volume, I have to keep my finger on a certain point, because a circle shows up and it needs to be full before recognizing a press. It looks like a debug mode, I have no idea how this happened.

My setup is: 2017 MacBook Pro with macOS Sierra version 10.12.6

Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zzkg9l50bn5wlvl/Screen%20Shot%202017-10-30%20at%2010.21.47%20AM.png?dl=0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently this is the zoom feature of TouchBar. It was already disabled, I have enabled and then disabled again before. To fix the problem,

- Open System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Zoom
- Click Enable Touch Bar zoom checkbox twice to reset its status, final version should be unclicked.

Comment: You save my solve!